# Can't get apache2.4 to pass requests to web2py using mod_wsgi

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, web2py, wsgi, apache2.4

I'm having a hell of a time setting up a web2py server in a way that allows me to access the admin and appadmin interfaces from anywhere other than `localhost`, which is a requirement for me because the web2py server is hosted in a cloud location without a browser or X server. I understand that to access web2py's admin or appadmin interfaces from outside `localhost` that I must use SSL/HTTPS.

The web2py documentation seems to declare two different ways to do this. First, from the [general web2py startup tutorial](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#Startup):

> The administrative interface, admin, is only accessible from localhost
>   unless you run web2py behind Apache with mod_proxy. If admin detects a
>   proxy, the session cookie is set to secure and admin login does not
>   work unless the communication between the client and the proxy goes
>   over HTTPS

This lead me to search the web for how to setup web2py behind and apache which lead me to the web2py deployment recipes page, [where it describes setting up web2py behind apache using mod_wsgi instead of mod_proxy](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes#Apache-setup). These are the instructions I'm currently following exactly, with the exception of updating the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/web2py` file to apache2.4 syntax and modifying the ServerName directive's value to "foo.bar.com" (omitted: the domain name of cloud box containing the server, this is replaced with foo.bar.com throughout this question).

However, when I get to the

> When you restart Apache, it should pass all the requests to web2py without going through the Rocket wsgiserver.

part of the that web2py+apache+mod_wsgi tutorial, apache does not appear to be passing anything to web2py for me. I went ahead and moved the `wsgihandler.py` file as the next step in the tutorial describes, and here's my current state:

- If I browse to `foo.bar.com:80` from another machine, I get the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page (the "It works!" page).
- If I browse to `foo.bar.com:8000` (web2py port), I the web2py server's default interface, but with no access to admin or appadmin because of the unsecure channel.
- If I try to browse to `foo.bar.com:443`, I get the generic "Index of /" apache server
  page. On this page "/" contains one directory link "html", which
  is a link to the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page (the "It works!" page).

Other information:

- I have an untouched instance of web2py installed at `/home/www-data/web2py` except that I've moved `/home/www-data/web2py/handlers/wsgihandler.py` to `/home/www-data/web2py/wsgihandler.py`
- The contents of my `/etc/apache2/site-available/` directory are:

  - `000-default.conf` (not touched by me)
  - `default-ssl.conf` (not touched by me)
  - `web2py` (created by me)
- I've manually started up web2py with `python ~/web2py/web2py.py --ip 10.7.166.27` (that's the IP for foo.bar.com (real domain name omitted))
- apache2 is running as user `www-data`
- The server OS is Ubuntu Server 14.04 x64

This is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/web2py file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.bar.com
  WSGIDaemonProcess web2py user=www-data group=www-data display-name=%{GROUP}
  WSGIProcessGroup web2py
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/www-data/web2py/wsgihandler.py

  <Directory /home/www-data/web2py>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(.*)            /users/www-data/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2
  <Directory /users/www-data/web2py/applications/*/static/>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Location /admin>
    Require all denied
  </Location>

  <LocationMatch ^/([^/]+)/appadmin>
    Require all denied
  </LocationMatch>

  CustomLog /private/var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /private/var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName foo.bar.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

  WSGIProcessGroup web2py

  WSGIScriptAlias / /users/www-data/web2py/wsgihandler.py

  <Directory /users/www-data/web2py>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(.*)         /users/www-data/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2

  <Directory /users/www-data/web2py/applications/*/static/>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  CustomLog /private/var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /private/var/log/apache2/error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Alright, I've solved this while writing it up, but I'm going to leave this here and wait my eight hours and then post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! I found my stupid mistake while writing this up. I had never bothered to properly configure apache itself:

1. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` were why I was seeing what I was seeing when browsing to `foo.bar.com:80` and `foo.bar.com:443` respectively.
2. apache2.4 seems to require the `.conf` on configuration files, I didn't have that so I renamed `/etc/apache2/sites-available/web2py` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/web2py.conf`
3. I didn't have a symlink to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/web2py` at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/web2py`, so I made one.

So, as of now:

- When I browse to `foo.bar.com:80` I get the same Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page, BUT
- When I browse to `foo.bar.com:80/web2py` I get an internal server error which the apache logs tell me is a python import error from wsgihandler.py, which means the apache<->mod_wsgi<->web2py link is up and running
- When I browse to `foo.bar.com:443/web2py` I get Chrome's yellow screen complaining about my self-signed certificate and after clicking through I get a permissions-denied page, presumably because of something I haven't set up yet in web2py/SSL

This means my original question is answered, but I might come back here and comment/edit if I get stumped again getting SSL to work.